# How do I make a render with a background image in Blender Render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image

How do I render an image behind my objects using Blender Render?

Let's say I have a cube.
[image: Cube]

How could I render this cube with a background image shown. Like when you press Numpad 0 with a background image selected in properties?

[image]

I've done some googling and all I found is how to do it in Cycles.
My last resort is to edit my render in a photo editing program. But I hope I don't have to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: you could put the image you want in the background in your render and that is in your blend to tell you the best way, I am very good in blender render (internal) so I will surely give you a good solution

Comment: edit your question and make some improvements like putting a screenshot of your problem that helps give you better solutions

Comment: ok i show you in a few minutes ok

Comment: Can you explain how you achieved your goal Cycles in a sentence or two?

Comment: is the same thing, only you need apply to plain or any mesh you need https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118361/62213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are plenty of ways to do this.

- Place a texture on a plane in the 3D View. UV Mapped plane.
- Render with a transparent alpha for the cube.  Place on background image by whatever image processing means including GIMP or the Blender Compositor.
- There are also HDRI images free for the background